# Azure Service Bus receive loop with parallelism

Tags: c#, azure, .net-standard, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm using the Azure Service Bus SDK (.NET Standard version) to receive messages from a queue and import them to a SQL database.
I use the [ForEachAsync](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/) method to improve throughput.

```
var receiver = new MessageReceiver(serviceBusConnectionString, queueName);
while (true)
{
    var messages = await receiver.ReceiveAsync(100);
    if (messages != null)
    {
        await ForEachAsync(messages, 10, async message =>
        {
            var success = await ProcessMessageAsync(message);
            if (success)
                await receiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
            else
                await receiver.DeadLetterAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
        });
    }
};
```

In Azure metrics, I see more outgoing messages than incoming messages, which means this code receives the same message multiple times.

What could be wrong?

Comment: How long does `ProcessMessageAsync` take?

Comment: Much less than the lock duration...

Comment: If you drop `ForEachAsync`, do you still have the same behavior?

Comment: Interesting, when I set the parallelism to 1, the problem is still the same...

Comment: I meant if you cut that extension method out.

Comment: Replacing ForEachAsync with a simple foreach makes no difference.

Comment: At this point I'm not sure what you're seeing. If you could share a simple repro via GitHub or similar, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: I'm using Azure Metrics to monitor the number of incoming and outgoing messages. The line for outgoing messages is higher than the other. (whatever the parallelism I use to process the messages)

Comment: But when I use the ReceiveAsync() overload that just reads one message, then both counters have the same value. I'm starting to think this is a bug in the way Azure measures outgoing messages when reading them in batch because I confirmed I always receive messages with different MessageId (no duplicate).

Comment: Yeah, I'm likely to believe there's a bug with monitoring than a but with message send/receive.